# list() function in PHP, is it exactly equal to brackets in the first of an expression?

Tags: php, arrays

I already know, the `list()` function in PHP is not deprecated.

It's working well since PHP 4.

this code:

```
list($drink, $color, $power) = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');
```

is equal to this code:

```
[$drink, $color, $power] = ['coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine'];
```

result of both:

```
$drink = 'coffee';
$color = 'brown';
$power = 'caffeine';
```

I just want to be sure both codes are exactly equal. and where is the resource in php.net.

Comment: [**Reading the Manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) is always advised `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are exactly equal.

- [PHP RFC: Square bracket syntax for array destructuring assignment](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax)
  .
- [PHP 7.1.0 Release Announcement](https://www.php.net/releases/7_1_0.php).